# U-Net predicted masks are all black

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I've trained a U-Net to segment some leaves images with a symptom of a agricultural pest.. so I got 3 classes, backgroud (0), leaf(1) and the symptom (3).

When I predict all test images, I got a black image in 8bit.
So when I opened (IMAGEJ) them and changed the type to 16-bit I can see the image itself and all 3 classes predicted, not a black square anymore...

How can I predict the masks correctly?

All test and train images are in RGB, and all maks are in 8bit (but in here, the classes are shown)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import glob

#Process each patch in test database
img_number = 1
for image in range(test_images.shape[0]):
    input_img = [test_images]
    y_pred = model.predict(input_img)
    y_pred_argmax=np.argmax(y_pred, axis=3)
    prediction = y_pred_argmax[image]
    cv2.imwrite('/content/drive/MyDrive/BD_filtred/predicted'+str(img_number)+".png", prediction)
    img_number +=1
```

Comment: what is `prediction.max()`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz argmax right? it returns the indices of the maximum values along an axis

Comment: no, I'm asking for the range of values in that array. I'm not asking what the function does, but for the result of calling it.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz its 1... i did normalize the pixels in my image before... when i did test_images.max(), teh result is 0.4593 ..... sorry, i'm kinda newbie in ML

Comment: if it's "1", now you need to check `prediction.dtype`. if it's uint8, the values must be 0 to 255. if it's float, values must be 0.0 to 1.0. `imshow` assumes this.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the dtype on prediction is int64, do you know how can i solve this? i want to those predicted pictures show those classes, so i have to convert to uint8? prediction shape is (256,256) should be (256,256,3) right? to show all classes?sorry dude, but like i said its the first time trying to do ML/DL... you alredy helping me a lot, thank you

Comment: right, I missed that it's a map of **class labels**. you might need to apply some false color. if you just scale the value range to 1.0 and float (just divide by 3.0) then at least you can see some gray stuff. that's a start.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz i'll try it right now... prediction shape is (256,256) should be (256,256,3) right? to show all classes?

Comment: ignore color for now. shape stays (256,256), just divide by 3.0 then the result will be float and ranged 0.0 to 1.0

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz i'm wondering if is there a way to calculate the time spent on a trained model? already trained them but i didnt pay attention on the time spent... now i need to know the time spent, should i retrain all of them again?